# how to get all html tags from html file in the list using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio, console-application

file contains tag as

```
<html><head></head><body><span class=style32></span>....
```

i want only the html tag i.e span,head,body in list.There should not be duplicates.
please help me i'm new to regular expressions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: If you're not concerned about 100% accuracy, you can use `</?([^ >/]+)`

Comment: Modified with lookbehind: `(?<=</?)([^ >/]+)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tagList = new List<string>();
                 string pattern = @"(?<=</?)([^ >/]+)"
                 var matches = Regex.Matches(file, pattern);

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                 {

                     tagList.Add(matches[i].ToString());

                 }
                     //to obtain non duplicate list
                     tagList = tagList.Distinct().ToList();
```